# My laptop's battery is 46% worn - what can I do?

Tags: laptop, battery, netbook, battery-life

[image: Battery Wear: 46%]
I've got an Asus Eee 1005PE "netbook" laptop with a 6-cell battery. The usage pattern has always been to let it drain down to 10-40% capacity and then let it recharge during the night. 
I realize that 2½ years is a respectable age for a laptop, and no less for the battery. [Soluto](http://soluto.com) is reporting that **the battery is 46% worn.**

**What can I do to refresh this battery?** (Besides replacing it, obviously.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Battery wear in Li-ion batteries is caused by decrystallization of one of the electrodes. There is nothing that can be done at the macroscopic level to reverse this.